# How to not clear input field onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working with React JS and I want to make a hidden button for a text box, of type "Row", such that when I click onto that box, a description will appear on the side, the Row has this structure

```
 <div>
    <form key={id}>
        <button
          className="name"
          type="submit"
          onClick={clickFunc} 
        >
          {data.text}
        </button>
      </form>
  </div>
```

Where clickFunc makes a call to enterMouseFunc, a function passed in when called in another component file:

```
const clickFunc = useCallback((e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    enterMouseFunc(e, data);
  });
```

In the description box, there is an input field,

```
// some other details here
<form key={id} onClick={inputClick}>
   <input
    type="text"
    className="inputParam"
    name={id}
    onChange={handleChange}
    />
   <button
    type="submit"
    style={{ display: "none" }}
    ></button>
</form>
```

My inputClick:

```
const inputClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
  };
```

My handleChange:

```
const handleChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setParameters({ name: e.target.name, value: e.target.value });
  };
```

Which works just fine. However, whenever I click on the Row again, or switch between other Rows, all user's inputs get cleared up. The page doesn't refresh since I already suppress this behavior, but the inputs still get deleted. How to stop it from clearing up the inputs all the time?

Edit:
This is how the interface looks like, where the grey boxes are of type Row. When we click on these boxes, the description will appear on the right as shown:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you by any chance triggering the `onSubmit` of the form? You prevent the `inputClick` but do not prevent the submit. However, im not sure it would be invoked. Why have a hidden submit button at all?

Comment: It doesn't work if I change the type to "button", in which case the whole page will refresh if I hit enter after typing some words in the input box.

Comment: Try adding an onSubmit to the form, which prevents default.

Comment: It still doesn't work, but I think the problem is about the Row rather than the input field inside the description. Becuase it's when I re-click on the "Row" box that this happens

Comment: By row you mean the inputParam input field? can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: No, it's actually the className="name" one which is the code at the very top. I included a snapshot of the UI, if it helps clear up a bit

Comment: Ah okay - doesnt that then mean that your  enterMouseFunc(e, data); event gets triggered, with data perhaps being empty.

Comment: The data is a parameter passed in since the code chunk shown above is inside a big function, and I console log to make sure it's not empty alr.

Answer (score 0):

Does setParameters contain all of the fields values? If so you should copy the existing values before reassigning name and value. If not the issue is elsewhere.

A fix would look like this if that is the case:

```
const handleChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setParameters({...parameters,  name: e.target.name, value: e.target.value});
  };
```

Comment: I used useReducer: `const [parameters, setParameters] = useReducer(formReducer, {});

Comment: where formReducer is: ` const formReducer = (state, event) => {
    return {
      ...state,
      [event.name]: event.value,
    };
  };`

Comment: That looks fine to me :( Good luck finding your error, I'm not seeing it.

Comment: No problem. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Unless you would like to submit the form, then you don't necessarily need a `<form>` element?

Also, having a `click` event handler on that element (instead of say, a button) is not really common, I am not totally surprised that it causes side effects.

What I would do is remove forms that do not submit: just the standalone inputs that trigger `setState`/`setReducer` on `change` events.

Then you should be able to remove hidden buttons, `preventDefault` calls, etc.

About the cleaning of the values, I suspect your `id` value in the `key` prop to change, which would cause a re-mount of the `form` children.

Comment: I also thinks it's the problem with the key prop that causes the cleaning of the value, but I don't know how to fix it. Could you suggest me a solution to it?

Comment: You need to share more code, so that I can understand how the `id` value is computed

Comment: when I click on Row, I will make a call to a function called `renderDescription()`, inside which I use `shortid.generate()` to generate an id,  and pass it into the input as above. My renderDescription takes in an array of values it will print out